# Get software key presses in a service

Tags: android, keyboard-events

I'm trying to develop an app that, according to some pattern pressed on the keyboard (like swipe, but not that complex), it will do some action. For example, if the user presses two keys at once, it will do some action. This has to be a service, because my won't have a gui. It will just do the actions. I read that it's not possible, as it would create a security hole, so I'm open to suggestions on how I can tackle this problem. I've thought of this way:
1. Create an accessibility service and get the key events (easy for hard keyboard, but I don't know about the soft keyboard.)
Could you give me any other ideas, or help me on how to get soft key events in an accessibility service?
Thanks!

Comment: The way the soft keyboard works is that it sends all events to an InputConnection.  Note:  it does not, generally, sent key up an down events-  most keyboards work by using sendText commands so what you want won't be possible anyway.  But for any hope of it to work, you'd need to implement an InputConnection and use it to connect to the keyboard.

Comment: You might be able to fake the system into creating a keyboard.  But if you could, it would not send input to you an simultaneously be able to type elsewhere on it-  it would be sending input only to you not to the edit box.  To get even that far, you'd have to use InputManager to connect the keyboard to a view (possibly an invisible 0 height view) in your service.  If so the ImputManager.showSoftInput() function on an invisible service in your app may be enough to make it work.  But it would not be permanent-  any editable field would steal it when clicked.

Comment: What about my idea of using an accessibility service? I mean, there should be a way for a talkback service to get keys so it can read out loud to the user what he is typing, right?

Comment: I've never tried, but as the soft keyboard isn't generating KeyEvents, my guess is it wouldn't be called.